# Can knockout.js components be treated polymorphically?

Tags: knockout.js, components

From what I've read regarding [the components feature just added in Knockout 3.2](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/component-binding.html), the examples assume that the consumer of a component specifies what type it is.

Is there some way for the consumer to say "component goes here" without specifying a type, and for the component's identity to be encapsulated in a property of the consumer's view model?

**Background:**

I have a control binding I've been using:

```
data-bind="control: weirdEditor"
```

The `weirdEditor` observable property has to contain an object with a `ui` string property, which contains the HTML for its view. The object itself is the view model. The `control` binding binds them together and inserts the resulting self-contained UI component in the containing element.

Looking around for similar patterns, it looks like Durandal has a `compose` binding that is pretty close:

```
data-bind="compose: { model: wierdEditor, view: wierdEditor().ui() }
```

Except that (I think) `ui` would have to be a path to some HTML resource in their AMD-based module system. I just make it an HTML string that I can `require` with a suitably extended CommonJS.

The advantage is that you can create generic containers (a splitter between two panes, a system of tabs, a grid with editable cells) such that the container is unaware of what it is acting as a container for. It can contain anything (and the contents can be replaced at any time).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `component` binding does support [using an observable for the component name](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/component-binding.html#api).

```
data-bind="component: weirdEditor"
```